# Unable to boot into Linux Mint 17

Tags: linux-mint, boot, grub

Since today morning the display is black (nothing happened, i.e. this happened out of the blue). While I could boot into Linux (I'm running Linux Mint 17 and Windows 7 as a Dual boot system), I tried to fix the display via hard reset. Since then, I am unable to boot into anything.

I've booted from a Mint 17.1 USB stick and tried the boot-repair tool, but to no avail. The two problems combined -- unable to boot, and display not working (maybe some hardware issue?) -- are pretty tough to deal with for me.

The pastebin from boot-repair is here: http://paste2.org/JOm86BFH

The thing I gather is that "The sda5 (Linux Mint 17.2 Rafaela) partition is still full. This can prevent to start it (e.g. you may get a Power Manager error)." but I don't think that this is the issue.

All help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use this Boot-repair again. You have installt grub for the wrong arch. `/boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img` but yor grub-entry says `Linux Mint 17.2 Cinnamon 64-bit, 3.16.0-38-generic` Take the Medium you have installt your system. It mußt be the same Arch. You have to create `/mnt/dev` and `/mnt/sys` `/mnt/run and` `/mnt/proc` `/mnt/etc/resolv.conf`in the Live-Session. Next steps

1. `sudo mount /dev/sda5 /mnt`
2. `sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev`
3. `sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys`
4. `sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc`
5. `sudo mount --bind /run /mnt/run`
6. `sudo mount -o bind /etc/resolv.conf /mnt/etc/resolv.conf`

`sudo chroot /mnt /bin/bash` 
Now you are in your System. `sudo apt-get clean` To make some place on your harddrive. `df -h;df -i` shows you how much place and how much inodes are free.

This slay every wrong grub-package. `dpkg -l | grep grub | awk '{print $2}' | xargs sudo apt-get install --reinstall -y` Attantion apt install at once without any request. 
`sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-3.13.0-24-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-24-generic`

Comment: thanks for you answer! I tried it, but it didn't work.

Comment: pressed enter too quickly.

I did install Mint 17.2 on the Stick (I had 17.1 before), and ran boot-repair again because it did not mount any of the disks. However, now I can't even boot from the USB Stick! Since the display doesn't work (something with the light), I can't see anything now.

Is there something I can do at this point, or should I have the hardware repair, i.e. also the harddrive?

Comment: What errors? can you post them? show `df -h;df -i` And backup your data for sure.

Comment: I can't tell you now, unfortunately -- I was too damn impatient. Now I can't even boot from the Stick! I can get into the BIOS, but that is about it.

Comment: After the Thinkpad screen, I get

2100: Detection error on HDD0 (Main-HDD)
Press ESC to continue

So I continued and can boot from the USB now. I paste the output from your commands shortly.

Comment: df -h

Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/cow            7.7G   47M  7.7G   1% /
udev            7.7G  4.0K  7.7G   1% /dev
tmpfs           1.6G  1.5M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/sda        1.6G  1.6G     0 100% /cdrom
/dev/loop0      1.5G  1.5G     0 100% /rofs
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           7.7G  8.0K  7.7G   1% /tmp
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            7.7G  804K  7.7G   1% /run/shm
none            100M   12K  100M   1% /run/user

Comment: df -h

`code`
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/cow            7.7G   47M  7.7G   1% /
udev            7.7G  4.0K  7.7G   1% /dev
tmpfs           1.6G  1.5M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/sda        1.6G  1.6G     0 100% /cdrom
/dev/loop0      1.5G  1.5G     0 100% /rofs
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           7.7G  8.0K  7.7G   1% /tmp
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            7.7G  804K  7.7G   1% /run/shm
none            100M   12K  100M   1% /run/user
`code`

Comment: df -h yields

`
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/cow            7.7G   47M  7.7G   1% /
udev            7.7G  4.0K  7.7G   1% /dev
tmpfs           1.6G  1.5M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/sda        1.6G  1.6G     0 100% /cdrom
/dev/loop0      1.5G  1.5G     0 100% /rofs
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           7.7G  8.0K  7.7G   1% /tmp
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            7.7G  804K  7.7G   1% /run/shm
none            100M   12K  100M   1% /run/user`

Comment: That sounds no good. Is your Harddrive a SSD?

Comment: I have a SSD, but I'm not sure it is the harddrive. Also, if I want to install Linux Mint from the USB Stick, it tells me that I have too little space. Is it possible that the harddrive has been erased? GParted tells me

"Not all of the space available to /dev/sda appears to be used, you can fix the GPT to use all of the space (an extre 12915200 blocks) or continue with the current setting?"

Comment: Can you connect the drive extern with a USB-Abtapter? `sudo parted -l`

Comment: I don|t know what you mean exactly, but I can see a USB drive when I plug one in and start GParted

Comment: when I want to install Mint, it says that it did not detect any operating system! what to do? can I get the data somehow, or is all lost?

Comment: I mean if you can take out from Notebook and connect to usb. For this you need a adapter  or a case.  <https://www.google.de/search?q=usb-adapter+f%C3%BCr+festplatten.&prmd=ivns&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiq79CB5NXPAhVD2hoKHd-HBFEQ_AUIBQ> from Live-session `sudo parted -l`

Comment: Take the hard drive out? You mean I can then connect to it, and somehow get the data? I don't know how to take it out. sudo parted -l does not much in the live session.

Comment: miraculously, I could see my partitions and tried your solution. now grub is installed, and I can boot into both linux and windows. thank you so much for your help! I still sometimes get an error "file system not found", and then I get a grub rescue shell, but this is probably due to the damaged harddrive

Comment: I hope you read this. fdabl. I forgott something ipmortant. `sudo grub-install /dev/sda` and `sudo update-grub`